# What am I doing wrong in my C binary search code? (iterative & recursive)

Tags: c, algorithm, recursion, search, binary-search

What am I doing wrong here?
The prototypes aren't changeable.
I need to write both of the functions and this is what I wrote.
They work at 90% of the times. The iterative way got an issue when i'm trying to search for the middle element.

And the recursive way got some issue but I don't really know what's wrong. Sometimes it finds the element and other times not.

One more thing I cannot change it's that I **must** avoid checking inside of the function whether `array[middle] == key`. The teacher wants us to do this check only when I exit the loop, and he wants the loop to only check if should I go right or left.

```
int *BinarySearchIter(const int SortedArray[], int key, size_t length)
{
    /*  variables that will set the boundries of the searched area      */
    int left_index = 0, right_index = 0, middle = 0;
    int *result = NULL;
    
    assert(SortedArray);
    assert(length);
    
    left_index = 0;             /*  first elemenet in the array         */
    right_index = length - 1;   /*  last elemenet in the  array         */

    /* while only one elemenet is left in the searched area             */
    while (left_index <= right_index)
    {
        /* split it to half                                             */
        middle = (left_index + right_index) / 2;
        
        /*  if key greater, ignore left half, search only in right half */
        if (SortedArray[middle] < key)
        {
            left_index = middle + 1;
        }
        /*  if key smaller, ignore right half, search only in left half */
        else
        {
            right_index = middle - 1;
        }
    }

    /*  if we reach here, then element is the key or was not found      */
    result = (int *)SortedArray + middle;
            
    return (key == *result ? result : NULL);
}
/******************************************************************************/
int *BinarySearchRec(const int SortedArray[], int key, size_t length)
{
    int left_index = 0; /*  first elemenet of the array */
    int right_index = length - 1; /* last elemenet in the array */  
    int middle = 0, isBigger = 0;
    
    if (1 == length)    
    {
        return (key == *SortedArray ? (int *)SortedArray : NULL);
    }
    
    middle = (left_index + right_index) / 2;    

    isBigger = (key > SortedArray[middle]);
    
    return (BinarySearchRec(SortedArray+(middle + 1)*isBigger, key, isBigger * (length - length /2 ) + !isBigger*(length/2)));
    
}
/******************************************************************************/
```

I was trying to run the following test;

```
const int sorted_arr[] = { 2, 4, 8, 10, 12};
    
    size_t arr_length = sizeof(sorted_arr) / sizeof(sorted_arr[0]), i = 0;
    
    int key_to_find = 0;
    
    int *iterative_res = NULL;
    int *recursive_res = NULL;
    
    for (i = 0; i < arr_length; ++i)
    {
        key_to_find = sorted_arr[i];
        iterative_res = BinarySearchIter(sorted_arr, key_to_find, arr_length);
        recursive_res = BinarySearchRec(sorted_arr, key_to_find, arr_length);
        Print if any errors (nulls or key doesn't match any of the results)
    }
```

And this is the output of the test:

```
ERRORS:

Needs to find: 8
But found:
Iterative: NULL (failure)
Recursive: NULL (failure)

Needs to find: 12
But found:
Iterative: 12 (success)
Recursive: NULL (failure)
```

Comment: In `BinarySearchRec`, suppose `length` is 5. Then `right-index` is 5, and `middle` is `(0 + 4) / 2` = 2. Then, if `isBigger` is 0, the length it passes to the recursive call is `length/2`, which is 2. So the recursive call will search two elements, those with index 0 and 1. If `isBigger` is 1, it passes `SortedArray + (middle+1)*1`, so `SortedArray+3`, and it passes length `length - length/2`, which is 5−2 = 3. So the recursive call is asked to search the elements with index 3, 4, and 5, which is wrong.

Comment: In the iterative code, if you aren't testing for middle being equal, then you can't remove it on the next iteration.

Comment: @stark the problem is that he doesn't want us to test for middle being equal till you exit the loop. It would be easy to just add `if middle==key.. return` at the beginning of the while loop. but he doesn't want us to do that. He wants us to find a way to check it only when you get out the loop and need to return the found index. That's why i'm checking it in the `return` line.

Comment: @NoobCoder: Stark’s comment tells you what a problem is. It does not say to test for the middle being equal. It says, since you cannot test for the middle being equal, do not remove it when preparing for the next iteration. Assigning `right_index = middle - 1;` is wrong because it excludes the middle. Since you did not test the middle for being equal, you cannot exclude it. The assignment should be `right_index = middle;`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Hey and thanks for your answer. If we suppose `length` is 5 it means that the `right_index` is `4` because `right index = length - 1`. `middle` is indeed `2` in that case. Then if `isBigger` is `0` which means they `key` is smaller than the `middle`, we need to scan for the left side of the array. it passes to the recursive call: `The original start of SortedArray[] as start, key, and 2 as a length and..` ok to be honest I got lost. Can you point out what exactly should I fix? Maybe insead of `length/2` should I sent `length/2 + 1?`

Comment: @stark Ok I understood your menaing now. I changed it to `right_index = middle`  instead of `middle - 1` but now it never gets out of the loop of `while (left_index <= right_index)`

Comment: Go through it by hand for odd and even array lengths and see whether the values are correct for the next iteration.  Also check your end condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **For Iterative Function**

Let's think what your code is doing. You have an array consists 5 elements and let's say you are searching for **8**.

```
2 4 8 10 12
    ^
```

In the first iteration the values are like this:

```
left_index = 0, right_index = 4, middle_index = 2
```

In the if statement the program checks for **(SortedArray[middle_index] < key)** and that is wrong because 8 is not bigger than 8. So it executes the else statement. The mistake is here.

In the else statement you are discarding the middle element. But in this case middle element is the key that you are looking for.

**So first thing that you need to change just like [@Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil) said is changing your else statement to this:**

```
else {
  right_index = middle;
}
```

Let's continue with second iteration:

```
2 4 8
  ^
left_index = 0, right_index = 2, middle_index = 1
```

After the second iteration, third iteration is only going to consist 1 element.

```
8
left_index = 2, right_index = 2, middle_index = 2
```

At this point the program stucks in the infinite loop because it always executes the else statement. Left and right indexes always stay same.

**So the second change that you need to do is changing your while condition to this:**

```
while (left_index < right_index)
```

At this point when the left index and right index are equal, the loop will break. **Than the last thing that you need to do is updating your middle index again. Or you can use left_index or right_index (which one is doesn't matter they are equal).**

At the end, your function should look like this:

```
const int *BinarySearchIter(const int SortedArray[], int key, size_t length) {

    int left_index = 0, right_index = length - 1;

    while (left_index < right_index) {

        int middle = (left_index + right_index) / 2;

        if (SortedArray[middle] < key) {
            left_index = middle + 1;
        } else {
            right_index = middle;
        }
    }

    return SortedArray[right_index] == key ? SortedArray + right_index : NULL;
}
```

### For Recursive Function

Only thing you need to change is this:

```
return BinarySearchRec(SortedArray+(middle + 1)*isBigger, key, (length / 2) + !isBigger * (length % 2));
```

The reasons are same as iterative function. You need to include the middle element. For lower part of the array, the array length needs to be equal to **ceil(length / 2)**, and for upper part of the array, it needs to be equal to **floor(length / 2)**.

You can also do this:

```
const int *BinarySearchRec(const int SortedArray[], int key, size_t length) {   
    if (1 == length) return (key == *SortedArray ? SortedArray : NULL);

    int middle = (length + 1) / 2;

    if (key >= SortedArray[middle]) return BinarySearchRec(SortedArray + middle, key, length / 2);
    else return BinarySearchRec(SortedArray, key, middle);
}
```

Comment: Wow! What a perfect answer, you helped me to understand my mistake learn from it, and also provided a fixed code. Thank you, I appreciate it!
Before you edited your answer you wrote 3 things to fix in my `reccursive` function. Why did you remove 2 of them? I was going to ask you why should I add the `+1` in `middle_index = (left_index + right_index + 1) / 2; ` ? Can I just write `middle = length / 2?`

Comment: I realized there is a fix with smaller change so I changed the fix for recursive function. I added 1 because while I was trying to solve the problem, I didn't use first_index and last_index, I directly use the length so it caused inifinite loop. Than I find a solution with ceil than I implemented that solution into your code. I thought without adding 1 it will cause infinite loop. Than I realized you are using first and last index and it is not necessary to do other changes. This is a better way to do it I think.

Comment: Thanks. If you'll have any other tips and suggestions I would love to hear because your comment helped me a lot to deeply understand my mistakes in my implementation.